# How to add a button (with image) on a map using Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api, html

I need to put a button on a map built using Google Maps API v3.

I've seen this sample
 https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/control-custom

and that's good for me but I'd like to put an image (like this one http://www.freepngimg.com/png/15500-click-png-picture), in the button instead of the text "Center Map".

How may I modify the code sample to obtain it (sorry for the entry level question .... )?

Comment: Not sure if this is a GIS question but a javascript/html question

Comment: I believe this is what is trying to be achieved. [How add a background picture for a DIV, Google maps Custom Controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6933934/how-add-a-background-picture-for-a-div-google-maps-custom-controls#7054347)